# Неверная кодировка текстовых символов

Tags: html, css

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой, что на html странице на русском языке некоторые символы не раскодируются и отображаются как знаки вопроса?
Кодировка страницы задана - UTF-8, lang=ru прописан. Текст вставляется тегом

Проблемы возникают только с отдельными символами, закономерность непонятна, остальной текст отображается как надо.

[image: скриншот ошибки]
[image: скриншот ошибки2]

Comment: Данная часть видимо написана  в иной кодировке, для этого её нужно сменить и написать в редакторе. В любом случае вы всегда можете создать gist gist.github.com и мы можем посмотреть предметно.

Comment: В редакторе установлена кодировка UTF-8, набор текста вручную не спасает. Более того, при добавлении/удалении каких-либо участков текста из файла такие же проблемы возникают с другими буквами в других местах (но обычно где-то поблизости с прошлым). Так же происходит, если отключить стили, например

Comment: Выложите gist, пока трудно дать объективный ответ или код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что это какой-то глюк OpenServer-а, на удаленном сервере все отображается корректно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить кодировку в самом файле на программном уровне (это позволяет редактор Notepad++ к примеру - открываем файл, в меню "кодировка" жмем преобразовать в UTF-8) после чего **обязательно** в ручном режиме напишите тот текст который неверными символами отображается, после этого сохраните файл, и проверьте ещё раз.

Comment: Кодировка в редакторе установлена UTF-8, переписывание текста вручную не помогает